# How to get the point by the user? Thus the user who is logged on. (Only users points)

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

How do you get the point by the user? Thus the user who is logged on. his points, **only his**.

My Code :

```
          <?php
        $query = "  SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_point, role_title 
                    FROM users 
                    INNER JOIN roles ON role_id = fk_roles_id
                    order by user_point desc LIMIT 5";
        $result = mysqli_query($database_link, $query) or if_sql_error_then_die(mysqli_error($database_link), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo '
                    <tr>
                                    <i class="icon-pencil"></i> 
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:30px;">

                        </td>
                        <td>'.$row['user_name']. '</td>
                        <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>'.$row['user_point'].' Point</strong></td>
                    </tr>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you provide some more info. What is your table structure for instance

Comment: `"  SELECT user_point FROM users INNER JOIN roles ON role_id = fk_roles_id where user_id = 1"` This will gave you the number of user with user_id is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
      <?php
    $user = /* insert user id via either session */
    $query = "  SELECT user_name, user_point
                FROM users 
                INNER JOIN roles ON role_id = fk_roles_id
                WHERE user_id =".$user;
    $result = mysqli_query($database_link, $query) or if_sql_error_then_die(mysqli_error($database_link), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '
                <tr>
                                <i class="icon-pencil"></i> 
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:30px;">

                    </td>
                    <td>'.$row['user_name']. '</td>
                    <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>'.$row['user_point'].' Point</strong></td>
                </tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

For this to work you need to have a way to identify the user. This could be done by a login combined with a session.

Comment: you have an example to insert user id via either session?

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, put his id into the session scope and pass it to your query.